# .htaccess RewriteRule works but the URL isn't changing in the address bar?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been pulling my hair trying to figure this out but nothing is working.  I have a webpage at **mysite.com/test.php**   I want to do a simple URL rewrite and change it to **mysite.com/testRewrite/** The code to do implement this should be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^testRewrite/$ test.php [NC,L]
```

For whatever reason it's just not working.  When you go to the new URL - **mysite.com/testRewrite/** it works.

However, if you type in the original URL **mysite.com/test.php** it doesn't change the address to the new URL in the browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

mod_rewrite won't automatically enforce redirecting browsers from rewritten URLs. The rule you have simply says "if someone asks for `/testRewrite/`, internally change it to `/test.php`". It does nothing to handle actual requests for `/test.php`, which is why when you try to access **mysite.com/test.php**, it gives you `/test.php`.

Now, the problem with mod_rewrite is if you simply add that rule:

```
RewriteRule ^test.php$ /testRewrite/ [L,R=301]
```

which will redirect the browser when it asks for `/test.php` to `/testRewrite/`, the first rule will be applied after the browser redirects, and the URI gets rewritten to `/test.php`, then it goes *back through the entire rewrite engine* and the above rule gets applied again, thus redirecting the browser, thus the first rule rewrites to `/test.php`, and the above rule redirects again, etc. etc. You get a redirect loop. You have to add a condition to ensure the browser *actually requested `/test.php` and that it's not a URI that's been churned through the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /test\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^test.php$ /testRewrite/ [L,R=301]
```

This way, after the 301 redirect happens, this rule won't get applied again because the actual request will be `GET /testRewrite/ HTTP/1.1`, and the condition won't be met.

Comment: Hmm... we're getting warmer but still not workining.  I tried using your code and it's definitely changing the URL in the browser to **mysite.com/testRewrite/** but it's not displaying the page. Instead I get a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Also, I am not really trying to redirect because it's still the same page regardless of whether you tell the browser to go to **mysite.com/test.php** or **mysite.com/testRewrite/** it's still the same page. My understand of using mod_rewrite is that when you use a RewriteRule the URL in the browser should change via the rule. This way you can hide dynamic URLs and make SEO friendlier versions of them.

Comment: Oh I got it working now.  I added your code after my existing code and it worked!

Thanks Jon Lin.

Comment: *My understand of using mod_rewrite is that when you use a RewriteRule the URL in the browser should change via the rule.* Without the **[R]** flag, it internally rewrites the URI, so the browser's address bar remains unchanged but the page served is the rule's target.

Comment: @user1303972,  as well as saying thanks, you should mark the ans as a "tick" so that Jon get the reputation bump :-)

Comment: Hey Jon one last question. You wouldn't by chance know how to implement your code with a dynamic URL would you?  Like say for example instead of the original URL being **test.php** it was **test.php?id=1** or something similar.

Comment: You'd need to use a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} <regexp>` to match against it.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I'm getting closer.  I added this condition to the beginning of your code: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$ [NC]` Everything works except for now I am getting a combination of the pretty URL combined with the old dynamic one **test.php/testRewrite/?id=1** Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: add a ? to the end of the target in your rewrite rule: `/testRewrite/?`