# Rewrite rules error

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a simple url, but without generating google errors

This code works :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  lieu/([0-9]+).* index.php?com=location&lID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  evenement/([0-9]+).* index.php?eID=$1 [L]
```

but i want to add R=301 flag for SEO

When i add [R=301,L] :

```
The requested URL /var/www/mysite/index.php was not found on this server.
```

I know that R=301 flag must be used with http://

but when i try the url is not rewritting

Comment: Surely that target URL's not a valid URL.  That's a server path (directory path).

Comment: @Madbreaks ok but what do you advice ?

Comment: Please show us your complete rewrite block, including the 301

Comment: I have just this 3 lines on my htaccess

Comment: I see no `[R=310,L]` anywhere.

Comment: with the single [L] flag it works, when i add R=301, so [R=301,L] it doesn't work

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  lieu/([0-9]+).* index.php?com=location&lID=$1 [R=310,L]
RewriteRule  evenement/([0-9]+).* index.php?eID=$1 [R=310,L]

Answer (score 0):

Apache tries to guess whether a path is a URI-path or a file-path, and it's guessing wrong. When you are internally rewriting, a file-path is perfectly fine, because it's all internal to the server. But when you are redirecting, apache incorrectly guesses that your target (the `index.php?eID=` ) is a file-path and it gets flagged to be handled by mod_alias as a redirect. By the time the redirect happens, it's malformed as a file-path instead of URI path. That's why you're getting the `/var/www/mysite/` bit when you redirect.

Either add a `RewriteBase` to provide a URI base for relative URIs, or make your target an absolute URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  lieu/([0-9]+).* index.php?com=location&lID=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule  evenement/([0-9]+).* index.php?eID=$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  lieu/([0-9]+).* /index.php?com=location&lID=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule  evenement/([0-9]+).* /index.php?eID=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I do not have this error (/var/www/mysite/), but as soon as I add R=301 flag the url don't change. It works only with unique L flag

Comment: the link is good, but does not appear in the address bar of the browser

Comment: @bklups I forgot to add the `R=301` flags to the first rules

Comment: the modified url doesn't appear in the address bar of the browser. So i try this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9949115/940971) but error - `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ lieu/([0-9]+).* [NC]
RewriteRule  lieu/([0-9]+).* /index.php?com=location&lID=$1 [L,R=301]`