# Apache - Changling browser URL address with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, localhost

I tried to change the browser url from `localhost:8888/dev/test.php` to `localhost:8888/dev/testRewrite/` following the example of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949013/htaccess-rewriterule-works-but-the-url-isnt-changing-in-the-address-bar) on S.O.

At first, I tried the provided code in that question

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^testRewrite/$ test.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /test\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^test.php$ /testRewrite/ [L,R=301]
```

and managed to change `localhost:8888/test.php` to `localhost/testRewrite/`

But applying the same to the sub-directory `/dev/` resulted in no change.
I tried adding `RewriteBase /dev/`, moving the .htaccess to the sub-directory and even clearing the cache but it made no difference and the url remained `http://localhost:8888/dev/test.php`. So I think I have not understood the rewrite rule properly and am doing it the wrong way.

> So what is the right way of doing this? Also does the .htaccess need to be in the sub-directory or it can be in the root directory?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^dev/test.php$ /testRewrite/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \h/dev/test\.php [NC]` \n `RewriteRule ^ /dev/testRewrite/ [L,R=301]` \n `RewriteRule ^dev/testRewrite/?$ /dev/test.php [NC,L]`. checking the real request header in order to escape looping

Comment: @Deadooshka Isn't your rewrite rule missing a parameter?

Comment: just removed redundant in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit more tinkering and searching, I finally got what I needed

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\S*?)/test\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/test/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/test/ /$1/test.php [NC,L]
```

Regex substitution was the solution to my requirements

Comment: In the 1st cond+rule you get two same regexps for testing. It is senseless and expensive. Also the `(.*)` is better to concretize with non-slash string `([^/]*)`

Comment: I have updated my answer, is this what you meant? Since I just started out yesterday, I was still unclear with how most of it worked.

Comment: I meant this case `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \h(\S*?)/test\.php [NC]` \n `RewriteRule ^ %1/test/ [L,R=301]`. the `^` (an anchor) means instantly pass thru to first `RewriteCond` and the `%1` is place for its submask.

Comment: How may it be non working? Even tested with last Apache.

Comment: I updated the answer. Seems like `\h` was the issue. Is that a typo?

Comment: `\h` indicate a horizontal whitespace http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-Classes-and-other-Special-Escapes . I suspect your PCRE does not support it.

Comment: I'll look up further on this, anyway thanks for your time and support

Answer (score 0):

Considering your code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^testRewrite/$ test.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /test\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^test.php$ /testRewrite/ [L,R=301]
```

## The problem lies in the last line.

> ^test.php$

In Regex ^ symbolize the start of text and $ the end of text.
Thus ^test.php$ has only one exact match. "test.php" But what you to redirect is "/dev/test.php".

Thus your last line needs to be:

```
RewriteRule test.php$ /testRewrite/ [L,R=301]
```

If you want to be very exact, you could also make it

```
RewriteRule ^/dev/test.php$ /dev/testRewrite/ [L,R=301]
```

You might need to do the same in line 3.

Comment: Does not seem to work. Also I think there has to be away to make the paths relative without need the "dev" so that it works on any sub-directory

Comment: That should actually work with my first suggestion, since it doesn't start with ^ it will be active for any path ending "test.php".

Unfortunately I don't have a test environment to check this atm.